# glBlitFramebuffer based mipmap generation and glTexParameteri

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I have to fix a FBO / glBlitFramebuffer based mipmap generation function for a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY.
The algorithm calls glTexImage3D for every mipmap level with progressively smaller textures, then initializes mipmap level 0 of each layer with glTexSubImage3D, then copies the finer mipmap levels into the coarser ones using glBlitFramebuffer. This is the beginning of the command sequence:

```
glGenTextures(n = 1, textures = &10)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE7)
glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture = 10)
glTexParameteri(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, pname = GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, param = 8)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 0, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 320, height = 16, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 1, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 160, height = 8, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 2, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 80, height = 4, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 3, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 40, height = 2, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 4, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 20, height = 1, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 5, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 10, height = 1, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 6, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 5, height = 1, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 7, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 2, height = 1, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 8, internalformat = GL_RGBA8, width = 1, height = 1, depth = 11, border = 0, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = NULL)
glTexSubImage3D(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level = 0, xoffset = 0, yoffset = 0, zoffset = 10, width = 320, height = 16, depth = 1, format = GL_RGBA, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels = blob(20480))
glGenFramebuffers(n = 2, framebuffers = {11, 12})
glGetIntegerv(pname = GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, params = &1)
glGetIntegerv(pname = GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, params = &1)
glBindFramebuffer(target = GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer = 11)
glBindFramebuffer(target = GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer = 12)
glFramebufferTextureLayer(target = GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, attachment = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture = 10, level = 0, layer = 10)
glFramebufferTextureLayer(target = GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, attachment = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture = 10, level = 1, layer = 10)
glBlitFramebuffer(srcX0 = 0, srcY0 = 0, srcX1 = 320, srcY1 = 16, dstX0 = 0, dstY0 = 0, dstX1 = 160, dstY1 = 8, mask = GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, filter = GL_LINEAR)
glFramebufferTextureLayer(target = GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, attachment = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture = 10, level = 1, layer = 10)
glFramebufferTextureLayer(target = GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, attachment = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture = 10, level = 2, layer = 10)
glBlitFramebuffer(srcX0 = 0, srcY0 = 0, srcX1 = 160, srcY1 = 8, dstX0 = 0, dstY0 = 0, dstX1 = 80, dstY1 = 4, mask = GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, filter = GL_LINEAR)
<continues in this manner for the remaining layers and levels >
```

For some reason, only mipmap level 0 of each layer seems to be initialized. When I add:

```
         ::glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,  GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
         ::glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,  GL_LINEAR);
         ::glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
         ::glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

before the glTexImage3D calls, it seems to work. However, these parameters are actually set later on in time before the drawcall when the uniforms are assigned.

Does any of these parameters influence the commands used for mipmap generation?

Regards

Edit: The ::glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,  GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR); makes the difference. And for some reason, it has to be added before glTexImage3D.

Comment: Not answering your actual question, but: why not using `glGenerateMipmap` in the first place? That function actually was introduced together with FBOs, so any implementation having FBOs is bound to have it, too.

Comment: Because the surrounding function is used for different texture types and I don't know what consequences it has for the rest of the program if I replace the full function. Thus, I try to make a local fix first before I consider this.

Comment: @derhass: Is `glGenerateMipmap()` implementation constrained in any useful way (like being forced to support gamma-correct downsampling) by the spec?

Comment: @genpfault no, not at all

Comment: But note that blitting FBOs with linear filtering neither has such a guarantee.

Comment: Should glTexImage3D depend on the texture parameters in any way?

Comment: Ok, hypothesis: glTexImage3D only allocates the mipmaps if mipmapping is enabled, and it uses the min filter parameter to decide if that is the case?

Comment: @Desperado17 that hypothesis is incompatible with the OpenGL specification.

Comment: According to my research in the past there were OpenGL implementations that ignored the texture parameters if they weren't issued before glTexImage3D. Could this be the case nowadays? Mesa 19.2.8.